# Netbeans making a JTextField transparent not working

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I've put a background image on a JFrame by putting it as an icon of JLabel. But the problem is my textfield and password fields are not getting transparent. I've disable the opaque in the the properties of both fields. It looks transparent inside the preview of netbeans like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jkh6N.jpg

It has also generated the code https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcTP9.jpg

But still when I run the instance of the code, the fields have their own white background.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPcFU.jpg

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: post code here as it is next and not as picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the background color and the color chooser of the jtextfield. It resets the transparent component of the color.

Solution:
Don't use the color chooser. Use the option "Custom code".
Then set the color to

```
new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255, 0)
```

(opaque can still be active)

Your initComponents should look like this...

> private void initComponents() {
>
> ```
>     jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
>     jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
>     jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
>
>     setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
>     setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 0));
>
>     jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
>
>     jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
>
>     jTextField1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
>     jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
>     [...]
> ```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for the help, really appreciate it :)

Comment: Using alpha based colours is not how to make component transparent in Swing, Swing only obeys the `opaque` property - using a alpha based colour in this way will produce painting artefacts

Comment: Based on my research, you need a combination of both a alpha based color AND setting the opaque property to false

Answer (score 2):

Swing only supports fully opaque or fully transparent components, it doesn't support translucent (or alpha based) colors.

This means that you need to change the `opaque` property of the component.

Setting the background color of a component to a alpha based color is a naive approach which shows a lack of understanding into how the painting process actually works and which leads to more "unexpected" issues and more questions been posted on here unnecessarily

Except, `JTextField` (and probably the family of `JTextComponent`s) seem to be the exception of the rule.

The UI paint delegate of text components not only renderers the text, but also renders the background color, which on some platforms seems to ignore the `opaque` property.

What to do in this case?  Well, in this case you have to do both.

```
jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
jTextField1.setOpaque(false);
jTextField1..setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255, 0));
```

You can find the `opaque` property in the property sheet